# executing ant script from java class

Tags: java, ant

I want to run an ant script runANTScript.xml from my java class. The script is located in SCRIPTS/ folder of my web application. I tried to run file like this

```
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    String command="ant -f SCRIPTS/runANTScript.xml"
    Process p;
    try {

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this gives an error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ant": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
at my.Abc.executeCommand(Abc.java:48)
```

I am able to run by using code below but it import classes from ant.jar and i don't want to use jar file.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper;
 Project project = new Project();
    File buildFile = new File(buildXmlFileFullPath);
    project.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
    project.addBuildListener(consoleLogger);

    // Capture event for Ant script build start / stop / failure
    try {
        project.fireBuildStarted();
        project.init();
        ProjectHelper projectHelper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", projectHelper);
        projectHelper.parse(project, buildFile);

        // If no target specified then default target will be executed.
        String targetToExecute = (target != null && target.trim().length() > 0) ? target.trim() : project.getDefaultTarget();
        project.executeTarget(targetToExecute);
        project.fireBuildFinished(null);
        success = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

1. to include the path of ant executable so that the java `exec()` knows where to find it.

*or*

2. Call ant with its *absolute path*.

The first task is a bit complicated, as PATH environmental variable is evaluated really early during the boot process (e.g. `java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/ant`)

Changing the system property later doesn’t have any effect. You could still use (or abuse?) the classloader:

```
System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "/path/to/ant" );

Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
```

Comment: Add ant libraries to your classapth and replace call `Runtmie.exec(...)` with

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding groovy to your classpath you could use [AntBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/AntBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Different Approach**

Add Ant libraries to your classapth and replace call `Runtmie.exec(...)` with
[org.apachetools.ant.Main.main(...)](http://javadoc.haefelinger.it/org.apache.ant/1.7.1/org/apache/tools/ant/Main.html#main(java.lang.String[]))

This is more stable, and has no dependency on a local Ant installation. Which need to be on the system environment `PATH`, or called with the full path in the `Runtime.exec(...)`

This will make Ant part of the created applciation and not a externally called application.